# Regex OR statement won't work without space after string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, match, space

I am trying to get this regex to match (once or twice) any occurrence of these strings: border-box|padding-box|content-box

Here is the regex:

```
((?:border-box|padding-box|content-box){1,2})
```

Here is the sample string:

```
background: url("my image.jpg") left right 2px 50% 75% repeat-x round scroll border-box padding-box;
```

Expected result:

```
border-box padding-box
```

Actual result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => border-box
    [1] => border-box
)
```

Oh and btw I am using this site to test my regex: http://www.phpliveregex.com/
Note: I am using preg_match not preg_match_all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your pattern requires the repetitions to occur immediately after each other, with no whitespace between.

Try adding a `\s*` after the alternation to allow for optional whitespace between the repetitions, like this:

```
(?:(?:border-box|padding-box|content-box)\s*){1,2}
```

Or even better:

```
(?:(?:border|padding|content)-box\s*){1,2}
```

Note that because of the `*`, this will also match a string like `border-boxborder-box` (no whitespace between repetitions). If this is a problem you can try a pattern like this:

```
(?:(?:border|padding|content)-box)(?:\s+(?:border|padding|content)-box)?
```

Note that I've removed the surrounding `(…)` since this group would always be identical to the entire match, so it's almost certainly not necessary.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed. I was thinking it had something to do with the spaces, but I could not figure out a way to match them but not capture. Could you explain how the \s* works? I know that \s+ matches multiple spaces...

Comment: @LeinardoSmtih `\s*` matches zero or more whitespace characters.

Comment: So what is the difference with \s* and \s+?

Comment: @LeinardoSmtih `\s+` matches one or more whitespace characters. So the `\s*` essentially makes the space optional. This would be useful if you had a string like `border-box;` where there is no whitespace after the match.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So \s* does essentially the same thing as: \s+?

Comment: @LeinardoSmtih: Nope. `\s*` matches any whitespace character zero or more times, whereas `\s+` matches any whitespace character **one** or more times.

Comment: @LeinardoSmtih No. `+` means '**one** or more', `*` means '**zero** or more'. Which one you use is pretty important.

Comment: I meant the \s+ and the ? can do the same thing as \s*? (since the ? makes \s+ optional?

Comment: @LeinardoSmtih No. `?` means '**zero** or **one**'. It makes the second group (the `(\s*(…)-box)` group) optional.

Comment: @LeinardoSmtih Note that placing `?` directly after a quantifier (e.g. `*` or `+`) also has special meaning. It makes the quantifier '*non-greedy*'. See http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html

Answer (score 3):

**Solution using `preg_match_all()`**

You're trying to match multiple values, so use `preg_match_all()` instead of `preg_match()`:

```
$ok = preg_match_all('/(border-box|padding-box|content-box)/', $str, $matches);

if ($ok) {
    $result = implode(' ', $matches[0]);
    var_dump($result);
}
```

Output:

```
string(22) "border-box padding-box"
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/102023)

**Solution using `preg_match()`**

Your current regular expression doesn't work because it doesn't take whitespace into account. You can modify the regular expression as follows.

```
((?:(?:border-box|padding-box|content-box)\s*){1,2})
```

Explanation:

- `(?:border-box|padding-box|content-box)` - non-capturing group
- `\s*` - match any whitespace character (shorthand for the character class`[\r\n\t\f ]`) zero or more times
- `{1,2}` - match the previous group between 1 and 2 times

Output:

```
string(22) "border-box padding-box"
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/102021)

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for... I wanted to use just preg_match and I needed all the values in one value of the array. (like I currently had)

Comment: @LeinardoSmtih: You can just do `implode(' ', $matches[0]);` to get a single string.

Comment: Yeah, but I needed something more like what p.s.w.g. has. I wanted to keep it in one regex.